# IBM PS2 keyboard--cleaning the contact sheets

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I inherited an old IBM PS2 keyboard (made by Lexmark). I have read many guides on how to clean it, and also looked at some of the videos, but all of these seem to deal only with the keys.

Once disassembled, connected to the circuit board are two clear flexible plastic sheets with circuits etched on them. And below the sheets is a removal piece of silvered reflective plastic. I have found nothing that tells me exactly how these plastic sheets function. Does pressing them together under a key create the character, and if so, how are they kept apart normally? And how are they, and the reflective plastic cleaned?

I ask because a few of the keys do not seem to create a character when pressed, and a few others repeat the character endlessly.

Comment: What model keyboard is it?

Comment: IBM Model M2
Mfg. by Lexmark
Part #1395300
Mfg. 15-Feb-1994